# I'm trying to create a dynamic object based on the value of a column using linq

Tags: linq

Based on the values of a column I am trying to create an object with a specific property value.  How do I modify the following query to do that?
//object alertCode has properties of "code" and "description"  code will be set depending on what the alert_type value thats returned from the query.

```
var medicalcodes = new string[]{"M", "D", "5"};
var specialedcodes = new string []{"C", "I"};
var personalcommentscodes = new string []{"A"};
var academiccodes = new string[]{"R", "E", "S"};

List<alertCode alertCollections = (from a in alertinfo
                                   select new alertCode{
                                      where medicalcodes.Contains(a.alert_type)
                                       code = 'M',
                                       where specialcodes.Contains(a.alert_type)
                                        code = 'S',
                                       where personalcommentscodes.Contains(a.alert_type)
                                        code = 'P',
                                        where academiccodes.Contains(a.alert_type)
                                         code = 'A',
                                         desc = a.description
                                     } ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd moved code calculation to separate method

```
var query = alertinfo.Select(a => new alertCode()
                      {
                         code = GetCodeFor(a.alert_type),
                         desc = a.description
                      }).ToList();
```

Code calculation:

```
private char GetCodeFor(string alertType)
{
     if (medicalcodes.Contains(alertType)
         return 'M';
     if (specialcodes.Contains(alertType)
         return 'S';
     if (personalcommentscodes.Contains(alertType)
         return 'P';
     if (academiccodes.Contains(alertType))
         return 'A';

     // return default value
}
```