# LINQ to Entities create dynamic field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to create a dynamic field using LINQ to Entities w/ EF5. Based on certain conditions (which I've encapsulated in a function) the dynamic field will be populated with different values.

I referenced the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880630/im-trying-to-create-a-dynamic-object-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-using-linq) but when I run the code below, I get the follow error:

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String FormatName()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

```
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> SelectAllCustomers()
    {
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var query = db.Customer.Select(c => new
                         {
                             c.ID,
                             FullNameLastFirstMiddle = FormatName(c.First_Name, c.Middle_Name, c.Last_Name),
                         }
                        );

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    private static string FormatName(string first, string middle, string last) 
    {
        //format name 
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middle))
                return last + ", " + first + " " + middle;
            else
                return last + ", " + first;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middle))
                return last + ", " + middle;
            else
                return last;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how best to dynamically build a field with sofisticated logic using LINQ to Entities?

Comment: You have to write it inline, as part of your query, using `?:` operator.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea is to always pull these fields separately from the database and add an extra property or method in code that executes that logic when requested.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek the logic is quite involved so I was looking for a solution where I could encapsulate in a method call. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880630/im-trying-to-create-a-dynamic-object-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-using-linq) has a method call as part of query but when I try to implement this design I get the exception mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Post you're referring is not about LINQ to Entities. That makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

String formatting like that doesn't really need to be translated to SQL and performed on the database side in the first place.  Instead just query the database for the information that you need and then perform the string manipulation on the application side using LINQ to objects:

```
var query = db.Customer.Select(c => new
{
    c.ID,
    c.First_Name,
    c.Middle_Name,
    c.Last_Name,
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(c => new
{
    c.ID,
    FullNameLastFirstMiddle = 
        FormatName(c.First_Name, c.Middle_Name, c.Last_Name),
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write SQL which will do the same. And so can EF, if you inline the condition and use `value != null && value != ""` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty` call.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek He's not using `IsNullOrEmpty` he's using `IsNullOrWhitespace`.  And either way, the main point here is not so much that you *can't* do this in SQL, its more that *there's no compelling reason to*.  Unlike some form of filtering doing this on the DB end won't reduce the amount of data sent over the wire, unlike something like sorting it's not an operation that the DB can do much more efficiently.  And of course inlining all of those operations becomes that much more problematic if this is something he needs to do in a lot of different places.  The odds of a mistake are high.